# SQL server could not be determined

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I have connected to a Web Service, I have developed my code in C#, it debugs fully and recieves an error response, it gets this response from the Web Service - 'The appropriate Local authority SQL server could not be determined'.

There are three responses that are possible to get back from the web service,

Failure - in that it is not connecting to the SQL server (the error I am getting).

Error - Which means it is connected but in an incorrect format or values.

Stored - Which is a successful transfer of data (The one I want!) .

What are the possible reasons that the SQL server could not be determined?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hard to tell... can you post a code snippet, and maybe give us a little more context?  Maybe read this post about the best way to ask a question to get the best responses.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific error message that you reference

> the appropriate Local authority SQL
>   server could not be determined

Is not an error message that I am used to seeing, and after a quick search I'm guessing this is a custom error on your side.

There are numerous things that can cause you to not be able to connect to SQL Server.  To help point you in the right direction I think we are going to need to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here but I would say that the SQL Service is running as a domain user with some sort of restrictions on it.   I would change the local SQL service to run as a local user such as the local "system" user, and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes I have spoke to the cilent and I bleive it is a problem on their end, which is good news! However if not I will post some code at a later date, thanks to everyone for the input! I will try not to be so vague next time!